# Подскажите, где ошибка в коде php?

Tags: php

Делаю форму регистрации по мануалу для php5 на php7.

Вот проблемное место:

```
<?php
    //заносим введенный пользователем логин в переменную $login, если он пустой, то уничтожаем переменную
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $login = $_POST['login'];
        if ($login == '') {
            unset($login);
        }
    }

    //заносим введенный пользователем пароль в переменную $password, если он пустой, то уничтожаем переменную
    if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        if ($password =='') {
            unset($password);
        }
    }

    //если пользователь не ввел логин или пароль, то выдаем ошибку и останавливаем скрипт
    if (empty($login) or empty($password)) {
        exit ("Вы ввели не всю информацию, вернитесь назад и заполните все поля!");
    }

    //если логин и пароль введены, то обрабатываем их, чтобы теги и скрипты не работали, мало ли что люди могут ввести
    $login = stripslashes($login);
    $login = htmlspecialchars($login);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    $password = htmlspecialchars($password);

    //удаляем лишние пробелы
    $login = trim($login);
    $password = trim($password);

    // подключаемся к базе
    include ("bd.php");// файл bd.php должен быть в той же папке, что и все остальные, если это не так, то просто измените путь 

    // проверка на существование пользователя с таким же логином
    $result = mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='$login'",$db);
    $myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if (!empty($myrow['id'])) {
        exit ("Извините, введённый вами логин уже зарегистрирован. Введите другой логин.");
    }

    // если такого нет, то сохраняем данные
    $result2 = mysqli_query ("INSERT INTO users (login,password) VALUES('$login','$password')");

    // Проверяем, есть ли ошибки
    if ($result2=='TRUE') {
        echo "Вы успешно зарегистрированы! Теперь вы можете зайти на сайт. <a href='index.php'>Главная страница</a>";
    } else {
        echo "Ошибка! Вы не зарегистрированы.";
    }
?>
```

После ввода регистрационных данных вылезает "Ошибка! Вы не зарегистрированы." вместо отправки в БД.
Так понимаю, что проблема в этом месте

```
$result2 = mysqli_query ("INSERT INTO users (login,password) VALUES('$login','$password')");
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: вероятно проблема в скрипте авторизации, в вышеприведённом коде фатальных ошибок не вижу

Comment: `if ($result2=='TRUE') {` на вскидку... https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php других критических замечаний по коду нет... но код г...

Comment: мануал в котором предлагается написать `VALUES ('$login',...` можно в целом сжечь сразу дочитав до этой строки, а автора предать анафеме